# Find the sum of the roots of the exponential equation

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, exponential-function

> The equation $$2^{333x - 2} + 2^{111x + 2} = 2^{222x + 1} + 1$$ has three real roots.
>   Find their sum.

I'll simplify it first as:

$$\frac{1}{4}2^{333x} + (4)2^{111x} = (2)2^{222x } + 1$$

Let $u = 2^{111x}$ then:

$$\frac{u^3}{4} + 4u = 2u^2 + 1$$

$$u^3 - 8u^2 + 16u - 4 = 0$$

The solutions are $u_1, u_2, u_3$

$$u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = 8$$

But that isnt for the original.

**Please, only small HINTS, no answers please, thanks!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT :

$$111x=\log_2(u)\Rightarrow x=\frac{\log_2(u)}{111}.$$

Comment: mmm. still confused how this helps though?

Comment: $x_i=\frac{\log_2(u_i)}{111}$, so $x_1+x_2+x_3$ will be...

Comment: I see: 

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = \log_2(u_1 u_2 u_3)/(111) = \log_2(4)/(111) = 2/111$$

But that isnt possible, the answer is supposed to be an integer

Comment: nevermind, the person modified the AIME problem -_-

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The product of the roots of the new cubic is $2^{111(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)}$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the roots.

This is [2005 AIME I #8](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2005_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_8).