# How to solve for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following problem has three roots, find the sum of those three roots:
$$2^{(333x-2)} + 2^{(111x+2)} = 2^{(222x+2)} + 1$$.

So far, I've used the substitution, $y = 2^{(111x)}$, to come up with the equation $$y^3 - 8y^2 + 16y - 4=0$$

By Vieta's formulas, the sum of the roots in terms of $y$ is $8$, but I don't know how to get it in terms of $x$.

Comment: Try the product of $y$ values (not their sum), and note that for each root $x_i$, $y_i=2^{111x_i}$

Comment: It would have been better to fix the typo in your [previously posted question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924433/how-to-get-the-xs-in-front) rather than reposting it again. Plus, the answer was in the link @Winther gave in a comment under that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the sum of the roots of the exponential equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343747/find-the-sum-of-the-roots-of-the-exponential-equation)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Find the products of roots of $y$ instead.

$$y_1y_2y_3=2^{111(x_1+x_2+x_3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is slightly wrong. It should be 
$$y^3 - 16 y^2 + 16 y -4 = 0.$$  But that does not make a difference in the answer.

The trick is that if $\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$ are the three roots of that cubic, 
you want to find the sum of $x_i = \frac{\log_2 y_i}{111}$. You need the **product** of the $y_i$, which is $4 = 2^2$.  So the answer will be $$\frac{2}{111}$$

Answer (score 1):

From $$y^3-8y^2+16y-4=0$$ you get $$y_1y_2y_3=2^{111(x_x+x_2+x_3)}=4=2^2$$

Hence, because $x\to2^x$ is an injective function you have $$111(x_1+x_2+x_3)=2$$ Thus $$x_1+x_2+x_3=\frac{ 2}{111}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the three roots of the equation $y^3 - 8y^2 + 16y - 4$ 
are $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$. Then you can write
\begin{align}
y_1 & = 2^{111x_1},\\
y_2 & = 2^{111x_2},\\
y_3 & = 2^{111x_3}.\\
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
y_1 y_2 y_3 = 2^{111x_1} 2^{111x_2} 2^{111x_3}.
$$
Now look for a way to collect the term $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ 
in that equation, and it should help show the way to finding
the sum of the three roots.